# why generics needs extends when implements an interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface

For example, when interface1 is another interface, when I use

```
public interface Test<T implements interface1>
```

it throws an error, and when I use

```
public interface Test<T extends interface1>
```

there is no error. I don't understand. Why we need to use extend when the super one is an interface when we deals with generics?

Comment: `Implements` implies that your class will actually be an implementation.  An interface cannot, by definition, be an implementation.

Comment: @Aurand Nice explanation, didn't ever really consider the logic behind that rule.

Comment: @Aurand The code doesn't specify whether T is a class or an interface - nor can you, in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that you're using specifies that `T` must be a subtype of `interface1` - that is, it's EITHER an interface that extends `interface1` OR a class that implements `interface1`.

Thank goodness the designers of Java just gave us `extends` for this, rather than `extendsOrImplements`.